# How do I set cache control in response headers

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

How do I set cache control in response headers using `Apollo-Server`?

I'm using Angular as FE and Graphql Module & Apollo Client as BE for my application.

Below is the response headers. I'm not sure from where this headers are applying from.

[image]

I'm wanted to set my custom headers, How do I do it ?

Below is my sample code.

```
export default new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context,
  playground: config.isDevelopment,
  uploads: {
    maxFileSize: 3000000, // 3 MB
    maxFiles: 2
  },
  cacheControl: true,
  persistedQueries: {
    cache: apolloCacheInstance
  }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you check this link: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/

Comment: Did you install the response cache plugins ?